# uasort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function with Mock Objects

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to test a sort function, which is properly working, but it seems that I cant test the function with mock objects:

This is the function to be tested:

```
public function getUsersSorted($users = null)
{
    if ($users === null) {
        if ($this->sortedUsers != null) {
            return $this->sortedUsers;
        }
        $this->sortedUsers = $this->getUsersSorted($this->getActiveUsers());

        return $this->sortedUsers;
    }

    $iterator = $users->getIterator();
    $that = $this;
    $iterator->uasort(
        function ($a, $b) use ($that) {
            return ($that->getPointsFor($a) > $that->getPointsFor($b)) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    );
    $users = new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator, false));

    return $users;
}
```

The getPointsFor function looks like this:

```
    public function getPointsFor(User $user)
{
    $points = 0;
    // GameBets
    foreach ($this->getBets($user) as $bet) {
        $points += $bet->getPoints();
    }
    // Questions
    foreach ($this->getQuestions() as $q) {
        $bet = $this->getQuestionBet($q, $user);
        $points += $bet->getPoints();
    }

    return $points;
}
```

I don't see any modifications within my code which would cause this error message.

**Update**
here are all the other called functions, I don't see any side effects, but maybe I am wrong:

```
public function getBets(User $user = null)
{
    if ($user === null) {
        return $this->bets;
    }
    $c = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('user', $user));

    return $this->bets->matching($c);
}
```

This is the getPoints within my Bet:

```
public function getPoints(){
    if(!isset($this->points)){
       // This part is never used, since the points are already set in the test
       $this->points = $this->reloadPoints();
    }
     return $this->points;
}
```

The getQuestion and getQuestionbet are also not applicable in my testcase.

Comment: Are there any side-effects in `getPoints`, `getBets`, `getQuestions` or `getQuestionBet`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this `uasort` error is similar to `usort` error which is counted as a bug, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235387/usort-array-was-modified-by-the-user-comparison-function).

Comment: @Jhn I don't think that my code is using any of the mentioned functions. But Some of my "Bet" Entities are Mocks, so maybe mockery is doing some stuff that I don't know about.

Comment: You're using `uasort()` actually at your `getUsersSorted($users = null)` method.

Comment: I was talking about the described function in the related Bug. print_r backtrace etc....