# usort error using $this

Tags: php, usort

this is my code:

```
usort($chartData, function ($a, $b) {
    $aTotal = $this->getUserAggregate($a);
    $bTotal = $this->getUserAggregate($b);
    return $aTotal < $bTotal;
});
```

And my error is: `PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context`

What I do not understand is this code works fine on my own computer, but when I run it on my proper web server it errors out.

From the error I understand that `$this` seems to be out of scope, but how can I fix this such that it will work on all machines?

EDIT: here is `getUserTaskAggregates()`

```
private function getUserTaskAggregate($data)
{
    return ($data[Constants::ONE] + $data[Constants::TWO] + $data[Constants::THREE] + $data[Constants::FOUR]
        + $data[Constants::STOCKED] + $data[Constants::PREVIOUSLY_STOCKED]);
}
```

Comment: Are you in an instance method?

Answer (score 0):

The `$this` support inside closures was added in PHP 5.4, so it won't work with PHP 5.3. If you want your code to be portable, you have do to that :

```
$that = $this;
usort($chartData, function ($a, $b) use ($that) {
    $aTotal = $that->getUserAggregate($a);
    $bTotal = $that->getUserAggregate($b);
    return $aTotal < $bTotal;
});
```

Or you can upgrade your server with a more recent PHP version, it would be the best ;)

Comment: Hi... thanks for your reply. Yes upgrading would be a good idea. In the short term though, I tried your solution and now it says `PHP Warning:  usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function`.

Comment: It's a different problem. You can see some explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235387/usort-array-was-modified-by-the-user-comparison-function. IMO, the problem come from getUserAggregate() which modify somehow your chartData references.