# Using key sort multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

**Sort multi dimensional array**

```
$list = array_sort($list, 'name', SORT_ASC);
function array_sort($array, $on, $order = SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array      = array();
    $sortable_array = array();
    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }
        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
//Prepare Array List
$list = array(
    array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'A-Name'),
    array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'C-Name'),
    array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'B-Name'),
);
$list = array_sort($list, 'name', SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: what is error you are getting?

Comment: i want to sort array using multiple key

Comment: @GohilVishal Also please share your expected output.

Comment: Use this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809771/sort-array-of-multidiminsional-arrays-on-more-than-one-column-key-with-speci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809771/sort-array-of-multidiminsional-arrays-on-more-than-one-column-key-with-speci)

Comment: i got it thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you found a solution but just in case I'll write my answer, maybe someone finds it useful

```
<?php
    $order_by = "asc";
    $list = array(
        array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'A-Name'),
        array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'C-Name'),
        array('type' => 'suite', 'name' => 'B-Name'),
    );
    usort($list, "customSort");

    function customSort($a, $b) {
        global $order_by;

        $compare = strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);

        if($compare == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if($compare > 0) {
            if($order_by == "asc") {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if($compare < 0) {
            if($order_by == "asc") {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($list, true);
```