# Sort array using array_multisort() with dynamic number of arguments/parameters/rules/data

Tags: php, sorting, dynamic-programming, variadic-functions, array-multisort

I'm trying to sort any array with `array_multisort()` and everything is working great.  However, based on conditions in my script, I need to change the options.

What I have so far is this:

```
array_multisort(
    $sort1,
    SORT_ASC,
    $sort2,
    SORT_ASC,
    $sort3,
    SORT_ASC, 
    $arraytosort
);
```

I would like to write something that will allow a more flexible/dynamic payload of sorting data/rules.  Something like this:

```
$dynamicSort = "$sort1,SORT_ASC,$sort2,SORT_ASC,$sort3,SORT_ASC,";

array_multisort(
    $dynamicSort, 
    $arraytosort
);
```

How can I feed an unknown number of parameters to `array_multisort()` and have it modify the `$arraytosort` array?

Comment: `eval` it would be, but really, don't do it. I don't see why you can't do this with a loop and without `array_multisort`.

Comment: this was just an example... I have a multidimensional array with about 30 points of sort... as far as I know thats what array_multisort is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).  But I've never tried it on a built-in function before.  Here is an example:

```
$dynamicSort = "$sort1,SORT_ASC,$sort2,SORT_ASC,$sort3,SORT_ASC";
$param = array_merge(explode(",", $dynamicSort), array($arrayToSort))
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $param)
```

Comment: I had the same thought and went to try, and it does seem to work on built-in functions (despite the name!)

Comment: hmmm seems like a perfect solutions but I keep getting "Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag" even though it works normally.

Comment: Oh, try single quotes instead of double quotes.  It may be trying to pass the value of $sort1 instead the name "sort1"

Comment: I'm very curious about how the array data contained in `$sort1`, `$sort2`, and `$sort3` can possibly be stored as the `$dynamicSort` string.  Please prove that this accepted answer works by providing a runnable online demo link.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with this answer: "Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag"

For anyone having the same problem try this instead:

```
$dynamicSort = array(&$sort1, SORT_ASC, &$sort2, SORT_ASC, &$sort3, SORT_ASC); 
$param = array_merge($dynamicSort, array(&$arrayToSort));
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $param);
```

Note that i have used the reference to my variables "&$" instead of $.
This works great in php 5.3 but may cause error in 5.2 due to a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that the array sent to call_user_func_array() must consist **only** of references; it is not important whether the array itself is passed by reference. I spent the better part of a day troubleshooting this; the fact that the examples on the function page at php.net all used literal arrays led me to this page: [php Bug #49353](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49353). Problem solved.

This doesn't seem to be very well (or consistently) documented, so here goes....

These DO NOT WORK (PHP 5.3.3):

```
$multisort_array = array($arr1, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, $arr2);      // array of values
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multisort_array);           // array passed by value

$multisort_array = array($arr1, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, $arr2);      // array of values
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', &$multisort_array);          // array passed by reference

$multisort_array = array(&$arr1, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, &$arr2);    // non-constants by reference
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multisort_array);           // array passed by value

$multisort_array = array(&$arr1, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, &$arr2);    // non-constants by reference
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', &$multisort_array);          // array passed by reference
```

These DO WORK:

```
$sort = array('desc' => SORT_DESC, 'string' => SORT_STRING);
$multisort_array = array(&$arr1, &$sort['desc'], &$sort['string'], &$arr2);      // all by reference
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multisort_array);                       // array passed by value

$sort = array('desc' => SORT_DESC, 'string' => SORT_STRING);
$multisort_array = array(&$arr1, &$sort['desc'], &$sort['string'], &$arr2);      // all by reference
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', &$multisort_array);                      // array passed by reference
```

Comment: What is the benefit of making a PHP constant a reference variable?  Or do you just like the _look_ of variables with `&` in front of the dollar sign?

Answer (score 2):

From PHP5.6, you can use a variadic technique.  Simply push all of your sorting data and sorting logic into an indexed array, then use the splat operator to unpack the parameters into `array_multisort()`.  Be sure to make the array that you wish to modify -- modifiable by reference before pushing it into the parameters array.

The pushing of parameters into `$sortingParams` below can be written more succinctly as a single declaration, but I think it will be easier to conceptualize this way.  These individual pushes would be suitable inside of an iterating process (e.g. `foreach()`).

For every column of data used to sort the parent array, you may elect to push zero, one, or two additional elements to best signify the sorting logic.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dbq2F))

```
$array = [
    ['number' => 2, 'letter' => 'a', 'price' => 9.99], 
    ['number' => 3, 'letter' => 'b', 'price' => 9.99], 
    ['number' => 1, 'letter' => 'c', 'price' => 9.50],
    ['number' => 1, 'letter' => 'd', 'price' => 10],
    ['number' => 1, 'letter' => 'e', 'price' => 9.99],
];

$sortingParams[] = array_column($array, 'number');  // 1-dimensional
$sortingParams[] = SORT_ASC;                        // this is omittable as well because it is assumed (just for demo)
$sortingParams[] = array_column($array, 'price');   // 1-dimensional
$sortingParams[] = SORT_DESC;
$sortingParams[] = SORT_NUMERIC;                    // this is omittable as well because it is assumed (just for demo)
$sortingParams[] = &$array;                         // this is the actual master array which should be modified

array_multisort(...$sortingParams);                 // unpack with splat operator
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'number' => 1,
    'letter' => 'd',
    'price' => 10,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'number' => 1,
    'letter' => 'e',
    'price' => 9.99,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'number' => 1,
    'letter' => 'c',
    'price' => 9.5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'number' => 2,
    'letter' => 'a',
    'price' => 9.99,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'number' => 3,
    'letter' => 'b',
    'price' => 9.99,
  ),
)
```

This technique is super powerful if you have dynamic rules being passed to your process.  In my case, I needed to collect filters from my DataTables UI and regenerate the data as a .csv.  I merely needed to iterate through DataTable's order data and derive my set of rules - done.

I find this syntax much kinder on the eyes versus `call_user_func_array()`.

Here is a more complex implementation: [Sort array of associative arrays on multiple columns using specified sorting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/809771/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the existing answers, just thought I would add a little something. For anyone passing the desired "sort by" as a comma-separated $_POST variable (or any comma-separated variable for that matter):

```
//$_POST["sort_by"] = "column_A DESC, column_B ASC, columns_C DESC";
$sort_bys = explode(",", $_POST["sort_by"]);
$dynamicSort = array();
foreach($sort_bys as $sort_by){
    $sort_by2 = trim(str_replace('DESC','',$sort_by));
    $direction = (strpos($sort_by, 'DESC') !== false)?SORT_DESC:SORT_ASC;
    $$sort_by2  = array_column($array_to_sort, $sort_by2);
    $dynamicSort[] = &$$sort_by2;
    $dynamicSort[] = $direction;
    $dynamicSort[] = SORT_NUMERIC; //or SORT_STRING or SORT_REGULAR ...
}    
$param = array_merge($dynamicSort, array(&$array_to_sort));
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $param);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do a very similar thing, but as my $sort arrays are also created dynamically, I opted for a slightly different approach:
on input I get two arrays `$sortColumns` and `$sortDirections`

```
$sortColumnsArrayColumn = array_map(
    function ($n) use ($mainArray) {
        return array_column($mainArray, $n);
    }, $sortColumns
); //creates "$sort" arrays
                
$columnsAndDirections = array_map(null, $sortColumnsArrayColumn, $sortDirections); // zip both arrays together
$params = array_merge(...$columnsAndDirections); // flatten zipped array
$params[] = &$mainArray; // add reference to the mainArray
array_multisort(...$params);
```

I still get the warning message though, and not sure how to change that: "Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #2 is expected to be an array or a sort flag"

---

EDIT: Turned out my `$sortDirections` array contained strings, not PHP constants. Changing that solved the issue ;)