# Sort 2 child arrays with same keys by values of one array

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
$value = [
    'name' => ['silverado', 'civic'],
    'type' => ['truck', 'car'],
];
```

I want to basically sort both of these child arrays by the values of `name`, ascending.

I have this code, which works:

```
$value = [
    'name' => ['silverado', 'civic'],
    'type' => ['truck', 'car'],
];
$name_type = [];
$columns = [];

foreach ($value['name'] as $k => $v) {
    $name_type[$v] = $value['type'][$k];
}

ksort($name_type);

foreach ($name_type as $name => $type) {
    $columns['name'][] = $name;
    $columns['type'][] = $type;
}

$value = $columns;
```

I'm just curious if there is a better way of coding this rather than using 2 foreach loops.

Comment: You accept the wrong answer. It's [this result](https://3v4l.org/oLVbq) you want ? Certainly not. You want to sort on name, not on name and type seperately.

Comment: Your answer does not even work. Notice how in the 2nd array of your solution, they are not sorted appropriately. A `civic` is not a `truck`. Anant's answer worked perfectly.

Comment: The 2nd array is sort on the name. Have you check the link in my comment above. Is that order you wanted.Which output is different with your code. Check it, [your code result](https://3v4l.org/0YlET) and [Anant's code result](https://3v4l.org/oLVbq)

Comment: And the `$value` have different order, in your question. The first have type `'type' => ['car', 'truck'],` and the second have `'type' => ['truck', 'car'],`

Comment: I use the 1st `$value` in your question, so I have different order. Pleast edit you question, and make the two `$value` with same value.

Comment: It's weird because Anant's code, while not working on that website, works fine in my actual app...

Comment: Anant's code sort name and type seperately. While your code sort type and name both on the order of name column.

Comment: You were right all along. I updated the accepted answer.

Comment: Related, highly-dynamic approach https://stackoverflow.com/q/11108891/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_multisort`, check [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/787770286a6b1c8488b80e9372184055ed67cf65)

```
array_multisort($value["name"],$value["type"]);
```