# Dynamic array_multisort() without calling deprecated function create_function()

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dynamic, array-multisort

I have this function in my old php5 code that will accept a variable number of parameters and perform sorting based on the parameters:

```php
function array_alternate_multisort(){
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $arrays     = $arguments[0];
    for ($c = (count($arguments)-1); $c > 0; $c--)
    {
        if (in_array($arguments[$c], array(SORT_ASC , SORT_DESC)))
        {
                continue;
        }
        $compare = create_function('$a,$b','return strcasecmp($a["'.$arguments[$c].'"], $b["'.$arguments[$c].'"]);');
        usort($arrays, $compare);
        if ($arguments[$c+1] == SORT_DESC)
        {
                $arrays = array_reverse($arrays);
        }
    }
    return $arrays ;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
$alliances = array_alternate_multisort($alliances, "output", SORT_DESC, "score", SORT_DESC);
```

How can I replace this with a function without calling `create_function()`?

Comment: An alternate logic would be to use the `usort` function. On each invocation of callback you get two items and you need to compare the `output` for greater/lesser; if they're same then compare `score` and so on.

Comment: I must say the `in_array()` check is not very robust/reliable.  If you were to sort an indexed array and wanted to pass a sorting rule for column 4, it would be considered `SORT_DESC` and completely skip that sorting rule.  https://3v4l.org/SpYYR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead:

```
$compare = function ($a, $b) use ($arguments, $c) {
    return strcasecmp($a[$arguments[$c]], $b[$arguments[$c]]);
};
```

*Untested but should be close enough*

The `use` keyword allows you to inherit variables from the parent scope inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll argue that if you have the ability to hardcode this into your script:

> ```
> $alliances = array_alternate_multisort($alliances, "output", SORT_DESC, "score", SORT_DESC);
> ```

then you can just as easily **completely scrap your custom function** and just write this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1pKUh))

```
array_multisort(...[
    array_column($alliances, 'output'),
    SORT_DESC,
    array_column($alliances, 'score'),
    SORT_DESC,
    &$alliances
]);
```

**This will do EVERYTHING that your custom function will do and more WITHOUT introducing ANY custom function.**

This is a very concise, totally native, and instantly readable technique.  Using this means that:

- you will not confine your script to only `SORT_ASC` and `SORT_DESC`; there are other useful sorting flags to enjoy for specific scenarios.
- you can opt to omit the sorting direction parameters if you wish to use `SORT_ASC` (the default sorting flag).
- you modify the input array by reference like other native sorting functions.

---

Now anything beyond the above is going to introduce unnecessary convolution.  To keep this hypothetical (which, again, I don't endorse) demonstration simple I'll insist that the sorting direction flags are required like in your original snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bJXYe))

```
function array_alternate_multisort($array, ...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $i => $arg) {
        $sortParams[] = $i & 1 ? $arg : array_column($array, $arg);
    }
    $sortParams[] = &$array;
    array_multisort(...$sortParams);
    return $array;
}
```

- `& 1` is a bitwise odd check.  If the index is odd, push the constant into `$sortParams` otherwise push the column data into `$sortParams`.

---

This answer belongs to a family of similar answers that use the splat operator to unpack parameters into a `array_multisort()` call.

- [array_multisort and dynamic variable options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402337/2943403)
- [Sort array of associative arrays on multiple columns using specified sorting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419404/2943403)